# difference result for calculating power in python

Tags: python3, mathematica

```
1.2*1.2*1.2
1.2**3
```

When I write the first line in python shell it gives me

```
1.782
```

And when I  write second line it gives me

```
1.7279999999999998
```

What is the reason of this difference?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations).

Comment: Shouldn't it be considered as off-topic since it's a generic programming question?

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your typo.  Second, try 1.25 instead.  Then read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

or download the pdf version of the [Numerical
Computation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/pdf/E39019.pdf).